# How do I stop mail from automatically trash meeting invitations?

Tags: mail.app, calendar

Every time I accept a meeting invitation from Mail or Calendar, the invitation email automatically went to Mail's Trash folder.  Is there a way to stop Mail from deleting accepted email invitations?  Most of the times the invitation email contains useful informations, and I really don't want to delete those.

Comment: Check to see if the details are automatically added to the calendar event.  I use Outlook 2016 and this is the default workflow (accept meeting, email is deleted, details added to event)

Comment: @Allan It would lose all the attachments.  Besides, I always want to archive these emails, so I can search and reference them later.  I have looked all the places and couldn't find a way to disable the automatic trashing behavior.  Only if I could change it to archive, I would be happy.

Comment: Doesn't accepting the invitation put it in the calendar so the information is all retained? I wonder if you are using O365 or Exchange or some other service other than pure iCloud and apple mail and calendar. Also - is this iOS or web or Mac for your mail and calendar apps?

Comment: Even worse, if you search for it in Mail and click Accept again, it deletes it permanently, I guess because it was already in the trash.

Comment: @bmike I'm using google calendar and outlook. I really don't want mail to trash my invites, as most of the information therein is NOT added to the event.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a mailbox rule, that when a message is both in trash, and is a Meeting request, move it to the inbox (or a folder/area of your choice).

Screenshot is OSX which I imply that you are using. This would be possible on Windows too with a similar approach.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I cannot find these filters in my OSX Mojave, which version are you using ?

Comment: Alas this isn't applicable in Catalina - there's no "Kind" type

Comment: How do you filter for a message that is in trash? This filter only seems to run on New messages.

Comment: Worked for me on Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Thanks dude, this was getting on my nerves lol

Comment: Not actually working :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Catalina 10.15.5 and for email Outlook (not Apple Mail). It drives me crazy by auto-deleting invites rather than ASKING recipients where they want the invite after they respond. So presumptuous of Microsoft to delete invites which almost always contain useful info.

You can save it in your IN box by going to:
Rules - New Rule

RULE NAME:
Give it a name

WHEN A NEW MESSAGE ARRIVES THAT MEETS ALL THESE CONDITIONS:
Sent to/is: YOU
Subject or Body contains "invite" or "invited"

DO THE FOLLOWING:
Move to Folder - Use arrows to choose your Inbox

OK

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple Mail does not have the option for "Kind".  I am on 10.14 Mojave.
I did some comparing Email Headers and I ended up creating a custom rule in Apple Mail:

(This is for Apple Mail that is connecting to Microsoft Exchange Email Server using Office365)

1. Create a new rule in Apple Mail.
2. Choose Edit Header List
3. Add the Header:  X-Ms-Traffictypediagnostic
4. Select it and then select "Contains"
5. Add "MeetingMessage" into the third box
6. Perform the following action:  Copy Message to Mailbox
7. I previously created a mailbox and selected it: "Invitations Copy"

So far this is working excellent.  I have a history of all invitations in there.  The key is to not click on the buttons for them to accept/decline/maybe or OK if it is another meeting notice or cancellation.

Screenshot below.

Hope this helps others out there as well!

[image: Apple Mail Rule Creation]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to select "Attachment Type", then select the option is "Executable". Has anyone tried this? My MBP is running macOS Catalina 10.15.3, I'll test this to see if it works.[image: Apply Mail Preferences, Attachment Type is Executable Rule]

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: In outlook v16 (Check About Outlook) I can't select "ANY" of the rules are met. Also, I don't have the "ribbon" style options menu at the top, it's a grid like macOS System Preferences. I'm on Mojave

Comment: @DevinRhode this is unrelated to Outlook, this is about Apple Mail

Comment: I guess outlook and Apple Mail share the same problem